# How to delete one number from a contact which has multiple numbers in android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my application, I require to delete a particular number of a CONTACT from phone address book, but so far I just got to delete the whole contact using this code:

```
    Uri url = RawContacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String where = Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " = '" + name + "'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    return context.getContentResolver().delete(url, where, selectionArgs);
```

I have also tried to delete the number using MIMETYPE, but didn't get any success.

so please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I got from your question is there is a contact and it has multiple contact numbers. And you want to delete one particular number out of that multiple contact number. So basically its an update query for you. Do not delete, just update the number as empty string. This should work I guess

Comment: @HardikTrivedi how can do that, can you please suggest me any way or any tutorial? 

thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this post it will help you to understand the update query using content provider.

Answer (score 0):

Phone numbers are stored in the `Data` table, you need to delete based on the contact-id and the phone number itself:

```
Uri url = Data.CONTENT_URI;
String where = Data.CONTACT_ID + " = '" + theContactId + "' AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" + CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " + CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = '" + thePhoneNumber "'";
return context.getContentResolver().delete(url, where, null);
```

Note that `theContactId` is the contact-id of the contact you're trying to modify, and `thePhoneNumber` is the **exact string** of the phone number as you got it from the Contacts DB.

Read more about how data is stored in the Data table [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html).